# Disambiguation of [cloning] and [propagation] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki, tagging

The [cloning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning) and [propagation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) tags seem to be very similar to me. Unfortunately there is no tag wiki excerpt or tag wiki for [cloning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning) so it is not clear what is its purpose.

There are only 4 questions tagged with [cloning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning) and they seem to be general propagation questions.
On the contrary there are 210 questions tagged with [propagation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation). There is 1 that is tagged with both.

Should [cloning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning) be a synonym to [propagation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) or we just need a good tag wiki that would describe the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked up the definitions and cloning appears to be a subset of propagation.

[Cloning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning) : producing individuals with identical or virtually identical DNA, either naturally or artificially.

[Propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_propagation) : grows new plants from a variety of sources: seeds, cuttings, and other plant parts. Plant propagation can also refer to the man-made or natural dispersal of seeds.

I suggest re-tagging the cloning questions that are not really about that and adding tag descriptions for both would be of great assistance.